# find all occurance of 12 digits numbers and replace with adding 1000 to all of them in vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have a log file which contains time stamp in microsecond format. I want to replace the timestamp with some other timezone.

Timestamp format in the log file

```
043000000000 (04 Hr 30 Min 00 Sec 000 Millisecond 000 Microsecond)
```

should be replaced by by adding **0530000000** to it so that it will become

```
100000000000
```

I am simply trying to convert all occurrences of timestamps in CET to IST by adding 05 Hr 30 Mins.

I have a linux machine and a vim editor. I have learn that this can be done by vim with submatch with some math operation .But i a not being able to figure out how to do that.

Any help appreciated.

Prabin

Comment: I don't get how come `043000000000 + 0530000000 =100000000000`

Comment: @Kent: 4:30 + 5:30 = 10:00

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is indeed `:help sub-replace-expression`:

There are some challenges:

- As the match may start with a `0`, Vim's automatic String-to-Number conversion would treat this as an *octal*, not a *decimal* number, so `str2nr()` with a base of 10 needs to be used for explicit conversion.
- The numbers overflow Vim's 32-bit Integers. Fortunately, for this calculation, you can ignore the lower digits and focus on the first 3: `\d\{3}` matches those. To avoid wrong matches elsewhere, I've anchored the pattern to the start of the line with `^` and asserted (but not matched) the remaining 9 digits with `\ze\d\{9}`.

```
:%s/^\d\{3}\ze\d\{9}/\=str2nr(submatch(0),10) +57/
```

That assumes a simple linear timestamp like "seconds since X". If this is a non-linear `HHMMSS`-like format, because Vim doesn't have date arithmethic built-in, you have to write a proper *date addition* function yourself:

```
function! DateAdd( date, offset )
    " Split into hours and minutes, do the addition with overflow handling here...
    return addedDate
endfunction
:%s/^\d\{4}\ze\d\{8}/\=DateAdd(submatch(0), '0530')/
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly!. Thanks a  lot. But would mind explaining the use of each term in the above expression. I am a complete novice in regex. I tried to get some info from :help sub-replace-expression. But could understand very little. Will the above code search exactly 12 digit whole numbers  ?Thats what i need because timestamp occurs anywhere in the line.

Comment: And for **043000000000** its replacing with **100000000** which is correct. But for **050000000000** its replacing with **10700000000**. It should be **103000000000** . It should add 05 hr 30 mins to every time stamp.

Comment: Its a timestamp. hour field can not be more then 23 and minute field can not be more then 59 . So 0430 + 0530 =1000 . I know its weird task but i am really stuck. Plz help.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear from the question, and it makes things more complex, as you have to implement the addition yourself. I've extended my answer to get you started, but you'll need at least basic knowledge of Vimscript for that!